A new window for the sinc filter and its modifications
There is a recent paper in a journal called ACS Measurements which suggests an alternative window for the sinc function (Why and How Savitzky–Golay Filters Should Be Replaced) Link: Open Access Paper. This suggested procedure for denoising instrumental data in chemical analysis.
I am not a trained DSP engineer but as a chemist I am trying to understand the logic behind:
(i) choosing this window design which consists of three Gaussian distributions, one is centered at the sinc, the other two are shifted by two units, and then there are two additive terms.
(ii) have more additive sine terms in the following equation:
$$ \begin{aligned} a_i= & A \times w_\alpha(x)
\times\left[\sin \left(\frac{n+4}{2} \pi x\right) /\left(\frac{n+4}{2}
\pi x\right)\right. \\ & \left.+\sum_j \kappa_j^{(n)} x \sin ((2
j+\nu) \pi x)\right] \end{aligned} $$
One the web, the windows for sinc are relatively simpler, for the book "The Scientist and Engineer's Guide to Digital Signal Processing" by Steven W. Smith recommends Hamming or Blackman window. In the following suggested modified sinc, the summed Gaussian window and the corrective terms appear to come out of nowhere. I could not find any other reference.
"We also choose the sinc function such that the end points of the
window coincide with a zero of the sinc function. The kernel and its
first derivative are exactly zero at the end points, and its second
derivative is extremely close to zero. ${ }^{21}$ This results in the
following kernel function $a$ : $$ a_i=A \times w_\alpha(x) \times
 \sin \left(\frac{n+4}{2} \pi x\right) /\left(\frac{n+4}{2} \pi
x\right) $$ with the window function $$ \begin{aligned} w_\alpha(x)= &
\exp \left(-\alpha x^2\right) +\exp \left(-\alpha(x+2)^2\right)+\exp
 \left(-\alpha(x-2)^2\right) -2 \exp (-\alpha)-\exp (-9 \alpha)
 \end{aligned} $$ where $$ x=i /(m+1) $$
is zero in the center of the kernel and $x= \pm 1$ at the first point
outside the kernel, that is, where both the sinc and the window
function reach a value of zero ( $i$ runs from $-m$ to $m$ ). The
index $n$ must be even and determines how many wiggles of the sinc
function the kernel contains...Finally, the normalization factor $A$ must be chosen such that the sum over the kernel coefficients fulfills $$\sum_{i=-m}^m a_i=1 $$
Later the authors write:
For $n \geq 6$, the kernels described by eq 3 are not perfect in the
passband, however. We find up to $\approx 0.13 \%(0.01 \mathrm{~dB})$
overshoot for $n \geq 6$. This may be tolerable in most cases, but it
is not as perfect as the flat passband of the SG filters. The reason
for the imperfect passband lies in an imbalance of the side maxima and
minima of the sinc function, caused by the window and truncation. We
can improve the passband response by adding small correction terms,
replacing eq 3 with $$ \begin{aligned} a_i= & A \times w_\alpha(x)
\times\left[\sin \left(\frac{n+4}{2} \pi x\right) /\left(\frac{n+4}{2}
\pi x\right)\right. \\ & \left.+\sum_j \kappa_j^{(n)} x \sin ((2
j+\nu) \pi x)\right] \end{aligned} $$ where $\nu=1$ for odd $n / 2$,
i.e., $n=6$ or 10 and $\nu=2$ otherwise $(n=8)$. Like the sinc
function, the correction terms in the second line of eq 7 are zero at
the edge of the kernel $(x= \pm 1)$, so they do not compromise the
continuity of the kernel and its derivatives at the edge; this is
required for good attenuation in the stopband. We have determined
suitable values of the correction coefficients $\kappa_j^{(n)}$ for
$n=6,8$, and 10 , and $m \geq n / 2+$ 2 by minimizing a weighted sum
of the square deviations from an ideal flatband response. We found
that these optimum $\kappa_j^{(n)}$ values can be fitted by $$
\kappa_j^{(n)}=a_j^{(n)}+\frac{b_j^{(n)}}{\left(c_j^{(n)}-m\right)^3}
$$
The coefficients $a_j^{(n)}, b_j^{(n)}$, and $c_j^{(n)}$ found by our
minimization procedure."

What does it mean, mathematically, when there is a "$>$" symbol at the left or right side of an equation or mathematical expression?   On inside the denominator of a fraction? Like that "$>$" symbol appears many places in this question that don't make sense to me.

Fixed the issue. It was arising from the "quotation" option.

The paper appears to explain the logic. I will quote a few passages and provide a little more explanation that will hopefully help understanding. However, I appear to have improved upon their filter (see end of this answer).
"The sinc function sin x/x has a rectangular Fourier transform, that is, a perfectly flat passband, and a sharp transition to zero response in the stopband. Due to its infinite extension and slow 1/x decay, it is not directly usable as a convolution kernel; for application as a kernel, it has to be multiplied with a suitable window function w."
The sinc function is considered the ideal frequency domain low pass filter. However, it cannot be created because it extends from the beginning to the end of time. As such, you'll find a lot of approximations that people have come up with that are optimised in one sense or another. One technique is to isolate a section and multiply it by a window function.
"Gaussian windows have the advantage of having the minimum time-bandwidth product, and they also show fast decay... A Gaussian window does not have a finite width, however. Truncating it to get a finite kernel (FIR filter) would cause a discontinuity, which increases the high-frequency Fourier components..."
The Gaussian filter is considered the ideal time domain low pass filter and, importantly from their perspective, which they mention later, has no overshoot. Like the sinc filter, the Gaussian filter cannot be created either because, again, it has infinite extent.
So, now they're in a situation where they're going to have to do something drastic because they need to truncate these functions so that they don't have infinite extent, but doing so will result in a discontinuity in the function and/or its derivatives at the boundaries, which will increase the frequency response in the stop band, which is what they are trying to minimise. As such, they decide they will eliminate the C0 and C1 discontinuities and minimise the C2 discontinuity (notably this leaves the higher order derivative discontinuities, but they have to draw the line somewhere as it is just an approximation after all).
The C0 discontinuity is eliminated because they coincide the window boundary with a zero of the sinc function. The C1 discontinuity is eliminated because the window function is zero at the window boundary. The C2 discontinuity is partly eliminated because they realise that if they place a Gaussian an equal distance outside the window boundary as the central Gaussian is inside, then they will have opposite slopes at the window boundary, so summing them would eliminate the C2 discontinuity (see figure S4), but the fact that they need to do this on both sides means there is a component from the Gaussian outside the window on the other side that isn't eliminated. Incidentally, by keeping everything symmetrical about the centre, all FIR filter coefficients are symmetrical, which means the filter has linear phase, which eliminates phase distortion.
They then go on to say that things start to breakdown as $n$ increases, which they quantify, but they don't appear to say what value for $\alpha$ and $m$ they use in their testing. They then present a correction that they justify based on it being zero at the window boundaries and claiming that it doesn't compromise the derivatives at the boundary, and whilst it is true that it won't compromise the C0 and C1 continuities as the previously discussed reasons for these being continuous are still satisfied, it may affect the magnitude of higher order derivative discontinuities. They then do a numerical optimisation of the correction term to flatten the pass band, however they do not provide sufficient details to reproduce their table 1 optimisation results, so when testing their formulation I used their table 1 values to compute the correction term.
Now, this is how I appear to have improved upon what they did, with the result not requiring any correction term and achieving a flatter pass band. I found I can exactly eliminate the C2 discontinuity by instead defining the window function as:
$$w[x]=e^{bx^2}+a\left(e^{b(x+2)^2}+e^{b(x-2)^2}\right) + c$$
The C0 discontinuity is already eliminated because they chose the window boundaries to coincide with zeros of their sinc function. The C1 discontinuity is eliminated when $w$ is zero at the boundaries, thus:
$$c=-(1+a)e^{b}-ae^{9b}$$
The C2 discontinuity is eliminated when the first derivative of $w$ is zero at the boundaries, thus:
$$a=\frac{1}{1-3e^{8b}}$$
Here is Matlab code showing a comparison (I explored a few combinations of m, b, and n, and found that most of the time my frequency response looked far better, with the example I provided in the code being an occasion where it didn't differ as much, but take a look at n from 1 to 5 and it appears to be a significant improvement):
m = 10;
b = -0.2;
n = 6;

x = (-m:m)'/(m+1);
s = sinc((n+4)/2*x);

% me
a = 1/(1-3*exp(8*b));
c = -(1+a)*exp(b)-a*exp(9*b);
w = exp(b*x.^2) + a*exp(b*(x-2).^2) + a*exp(b*(x+2).^2) + c;
fir = w.*s/sum(w.*s);

% Schmid et al., 2022
w_p = exp(b*x.^2) + exp(b*(x-2).^2) + exp(b*(x+2).^2) - 2*exp(b) - exp(9*b);
if rem(n,4)
    v = 1;
else
    v = 2;
end
if n == 6
    aj = 0.00172;
    bj = 0.02437;
    cj = 1.64375;
    j = 0;
    s = s + (aj+bj/(cj-m)^3)*x.*sin((2*j + v)*pi*x);
end
fir_p = w_p.*s/sum(w_p.*s);

% compare in time domain
subplot(1,2,1); plot(x,[fir, fir_p])
title('time domain')

% compare frequency response
f = linspace(0,1/2)';
z = exp(1i*2*pi*f);
legend({'me','Schmid et al., 2022'})
subplot(1,2,2); plot(f,abs(z.^repmat(-m:m,size(z,1),1)*[fir,fir_p]));
title('frequency response');

This produced the following plots, which achieves much flatter pass band performance:


Thank you Stephen for your interest and reading the paper.  Also, would it be possible for you to share how did you reproduce the coefficients in Table 1 as you stated "Personally I found it unclear what the range of their summation variable should be in their correction term but computed it for the cases they explicitly solved in table 1."

I've revised that sentence to make it clearer. What I meant was I used their table 1 values to compute the correction term when I was testing their formulation as they talk generally about how they determined them but do not provide sufficient details to reproduce them. Therefore, reproducing the table 1 values would either be by trial and error or require contacting the authors to get specific details. For example, they don't state what alpha value(s) nor weightings they used when minimising the weighted sum of the square deviations.

Okay, good to know. I thought you were able to reproduce their table. The authors do not write this information clearly, their octave code in the SI also has coefficients but not the method itself . I will try to contact them. So this whole window is empirical based on the C0, C1 and C2 discontinuities.
